# Jquery array iteration json

Tags: jquery, iteration

How to iterate through the Json object?

```
var obj = { "field": {"row1" : {"col1":10,"col2":20,"col3":30},"row2" : {"col1":20,"col2":30,"col3":40}}}

$(obj).each(function(i,val) {
    child_obj =val
    while(children = child_obj.children() ) {
        child_obj = children .children()
    }
});
```

When I call children function on JSON object it does not get the children.

Will children function work only on DOM elements not on JSON?

How to loop through the JSON object and get the column values?

Comment: So, what's actually the problem here?

Comment: How to loop through the json object and get the col values

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: `children()` is for DOM only. Can you more specific what is your goal? You already done loop on the first level with `each`, you can do that too to another level.

Comment: How recursively iterate the JSON Objects?

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = { "field": {"row1" : {"col1":10,"col2":20,"col3":30},"row2" : {"col1":20,"col2":30,"col3":40}}}
$.each(obj.field,function(i,val){
    console.log(val);
    $.each(val, function(col, colVal){
        console.log(col);
        console.log(colVal);
    });
})
```

Have a look on this iteration. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amitfts/9s3Nd/)

Comment: It is working with the sample data I have pasted here. But doesnot work on my system. When I do foreach it returns the whole object with key.  JSON DATA  Object { "field": Object { row1: {"col1":10,"col2":20,"col3":30}} }

Answer (score 0):

Is this the one you needed? Please check

```
var obj = { "field": {"row1" : {"col1":10,"col2":20,"col3":30},"row2" : {"col1":20,"col2":30,"col3":40}}}
$.each(eval(obj.field), function(i, val){
    console.log(val.col1+','+val.col2+','+val.col3);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To Itereate through the JSON objects

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Bl_praveen2004/twf3F/1/)

```
var root = {
    leftChild: {
        leftChild: {
            leftChild: null,
            rightChild: null,
            data: 42
        },
        rightChild: {
            leftChild: null,
            rightChild: null,
            data: 5
        }
    },
    rightChild: {
        leftChild: {
            leftChild: null,
            rightChild: null,
            data: 6
        },
        rightChild: {
            leftChild: null,
            rightChild: null,
            data: 7
        }
    }
};
function getLeaf(node) {
    while(node instanceof Object) {
    if (node.leftChild) {
        node = getLeaf(node.leftChild);
    } else if (node.rightChild) {
        node = getLeaf(node.rightChild);
    } else { // node must be a leaf node
        return node;
    }
        console.log(node);
   }
}

alert(getLeaf(root).data);
```